# How to update the interface of a Powerapps app when changes are made in Excel?

Tags: excel, power-automate, powerapps

I am developing a small app in PowerApps that has as a data flow an Excel file hosted on OneDrive. I would like the data shown on the app screen to be updated every time the excel file that provides data is updated. I have managed to update the interface through the refresh function with a timer every x seconds but I want to do it only when changes occur in Excel. I think that perhaps with Power Automate you could create a flow that launches the refresh function when Excel is updated, but I don't see a way to do it. Any idea how to do this?

I need to update the interface of an app in power apps when the excel that is the data source is updated.

Comment: This might help: https://powerusers.microsoft.com/t5/Building-Flows/Trigger-when-one-specific-file-in-OneDrive-Business-is-modified/td-p/2054371